# Add area in Asp.net MVC in vs code or .net cli

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We could easily create Aria with graphical user interface in VS, but it seems impossible in **VS Code** and **Terminal**.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description, I assume your application is an Asp.net core (asp.net 5/6/7) application, right?

If that is the case, you can open the MVC application using VS code and open a Terminal, then, use the following command to install the `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator` tool and [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design/):

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design --version 6.0.8
```

After that, use the following code to add the Area:

```
dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator area AreaNameToGenerate
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

More detail information about the area code generate command, see [Area options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-6.0#area-options).